# Downloading from kickass

Tags: downloads

Trying to download a torrent with magnet link  can not get this to work with q bit torrent and Firefox, please help I am new to Linux

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu likely came with Transmission Bit Torrent Client.  Set that as your default client and everything should work fine